# Optimizing Neural Network Input for Convergence

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm building a neural network for Image classificaion/recognition. There are 1000 images (30x30 greyscale) for each of the 10 classes. Images of different classes are placed in different folders. I'm planning to use Back-propagation algorithm to train the net.

1. Does the order in which I feed training examples into the net affect it's convergence?
2. Should I feed training examples in random order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will answer your question

1. Yes it will affect it's convergence
2. Yes it's encouraged to do that, it's called ***randomized arrangement***

But why?

referenced from [here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_data_randomization_important_in_neural_networks_and_not_in_some_probabilistic_methods_of_classification_dealing_with_uncertainty)

A common example in most ANN software is [IRIS data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set), where you have 150 instances comprising your dataset. These are about three different types of Iris flowers (Versicola, Virginics, and Setosa). The data set contains measurements of four variables (sepal length and width, and petal length and width). The cases are arranged so that the first case 50 cases belong to Setosa, while cases 51-100 belong to Versicola, and the rest belong to Virginica. Now, what you do not want to do is present them to the network in that order. In other words, you do not want the network to see all 50 instances in Versicola class, then all 50 in Virginics class, then all 50 in Setosa class.  Without randomization your training set wont represent all the classes and, hence, no convergence,  and will fail to generalize.

Another example, in the past I also have 100 images for each Alphabets (26 classes),
When I trained them ordered (per alphabet), it failed to converged but after I randomized it got converged easily because the neural network can generalize the alphabets.

Comment: Why not backpropagate the average error of the entire training set? Is randomization only useful in batch training?

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri that will take more time and I'm also not sure it will converge well. Hmmm I don't think it will have big impact in online training.